# Python Selenium Webelement to Float

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I'm having the following issue:
I'm trying to convert my webelement to float.

```
asd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[17]")

print (float(asd.text.strip()))
```

Getting this error:

```
    print (float(asd.text.strip()))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3,56'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The string is not in the float format that python recognizes. You can either change it to a period (using `float(asd.text.strip().replace(",", "."))` or using locale:

```py
from locale import atof, setlocale, LC_NUMERIC
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "YOURLOCALE") # a locale where commas are used as the decimal point
atof(asd.text.strip())
```

Either method you use, you have to make sure the syntax is consistent over all the sites/pages you run your code on.

Comment: print(type(asd))
```3.56
<class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>```
tried that first command but unfortunately not works

Comment: Number is well now, but it's still "webelement"

Comment: @kedder13, can you post a more complete example of your code and the website you are trying to get data from?

Comment: This is a method I prefer to use.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
print (float(asd.text.strip().replace(",",".")))
```

Comment: print(type(asd))
```3.56
<class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>```
tried that first command but unfortunately not works
Number is well now, but it's still "webelement"

Comment: @kedder13 Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean `Number is well now, but it's still "webelement" `

Answer (score 1):

### text attribute

[text](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) returns the *visible text* of the element.

In your usecase, the returned text contains a **comma** as in **3,56**, hence `float()` won't be able to convert the returned text (which contains a comma) automatically into a *float* type. Hence you see the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3,56'
```

---

### Solution

You need to replace the **comma** i.e. **`,`** with a **dot** i.e. **`.`** and then invoke `float()` and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block using `replace()`:

  ```
  asd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[17]")
  # asd = "3,56"
  print(float(asd.replace(",",".")))
  print(type(float(asd.replace(",","."))))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  3.56
  <class 'float'>
  ```

---

### Update

Incase, you want to completely remove the **comma** character i.e. **`,`** and convert the resultant text i.e. *356* into *float* you can use the following solution:

- Code Block using `re()`:

  ```
  import re

  asd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[17]")
  # asd = "3,56"
  print(float(re.sub('[,]', '', asd)))
  print(type(float(re.sub('[,]', '', asd))))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  356.0
  <class 'float'>
  ```